# Single Click with touch screen on some web link

Tags: windows, touchscreen

I am the owner of a beautiful Dell Inspiron touch. Everything works like a charm, windows can be moved dragged and resized, links can be opened, with the proper gestures I can emulate right clicks and eveything is fine.

Except on some link. I can't perform the single click. This seems to happen in links that have the css "hover" behaviour. As an example you can use the website "chessapp.com" in which frontpage you need to click a button to start playing.

I can't click these kind of buttons, and I tried every kind of getures with no luck. Does somebody know how to do?

(note: I found lot of articles about how to handle this from a css perspective, this let me suppose that sites that didn't handle this are not accessible by touchscreen, but I wait for an expert suggestion / confirmation).